# Find nearest coordinate and print reference using Java

Tags: java, location

I would like to use java to read a set of latitude and longitude values, identify the nearest coordinates from a table of predefined values and report a reference name.

For example, with the input coordinates of lat=37.423423 and long=-122.083953, I would like to find the nearest point from the input table below and report the relevant grid reference.

```
lat     long     gridRef
37.00   -121.50  A1
37.00   -122.00  A2
37.00   -122.50  A3
37.50   -121.50  B1
37.50   -122.00  B2
37.50   -122.50  B3
38.00   -121.50  C1
38.00   -122.00  C2
38.00   -122.50  C3
```

In this example the output should print "B2"

I have some code which can report the coordinates for the nearest point:

```
public class ClosestPoint {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final int X = 0;
      final int Y = 1;

      // input coordinates to search against
      double[] coordinate = {37.423423, -122.083953};

      // input points to search against
      double[][] points = {{37.00, -121.50},  // 0  A1
                           {37.00, -122.00},  // 1  A2
                           {37.00, -122.50},  // 2  A3
                           {37.50, -121.50},  // 3  B1
                           {37.50, -122.00},  // 4  B2
                           {37.50, -122.50},  // 5  B3
                           {38.00, -121.50},  // 6  C1
                           {38.00, -122.00},  // 7  C2
                           {38.00, -122.50}   // 8  C3
                           };

      double[] closest = nearestPoint(coordinate, points);
      System.out.println("("+closest[X]+", "+closest[Y]+")");
      double d = distance(coordinate[X], coordinate[Y], closest[X], closest[Y]);
      System.out.println("Distance: "+ d);
   }

   public static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
      double x = Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2);
      double y = Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2);
      return Math.sqrt( x + y );
   }

   public static double[] nearestPoint(double[] coordinate, double[][] points) {
      final int X = 0;
      final int Y = 1;
      double[] closestPoint = points[0];
      double closestDist = distance(coordinate[X], coordinate[Y],
                                    closestPoint[X], closestPoint[Y]);

      // Traverse the array
      for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
         double dist = distance(coordinate[X], coordinate[Y],
                                points[i][X], points[i][Y]);
         if (dist < closestDist && dist != 0.0) {
            closestDist = dist;
            closestPoint = points[i];
         }
      }

      return closestPoint;
   }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
(37.5, -122.0)
Distance: 0.11363161152601435
```

What I would like to do now is output a reference name for this coordinate, which is B2 in the example above.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Best wishes
Ollie

Comment: I recommend to use the Eucledean distance, in this case. Really simple to implement, either.

Comment: I have edited the post to show how far I have got, which is only to report the closest point. I am currently trying to figure out how to report a reference name for the closest point. Many thanks for the suggestions so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance can be calculated using the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). An example of implementation in Java can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/vananth22/888ed9a22105670e7a4092bdcf0d72e4

EDIT: Your distance calculation will not be particular accurate on a sphere/curved surface. If accuracy is a requirement I would recommend to implement the Haversine formula as written above.

However, it seems like your question is more related to mapping an area name to a set of coordinates? If that is the case, there are a few different solutions to this (a few listed below):

1. You can create a struct (class) to hold the area tag (name), lat and lon coords and store an instance for each coord pair in a list.
2. You can  store the coords pair in one list as you do now, and the tag (name) in a separate string list matching the indices in the coords list.
3. You can store each coord pair in a hashmap with the tag name as key.

Furthermore, I would recommend to sort the list of coords according to for example the distance from a fixed point. This way, it is possible to find the closest point to the given coord doing a simple binary search instead of having to iterate over each coord in the list (O(N) in worst case).

EDIT2:

Here is an example where I modified your original code. This is not an optimal solution, I recommend to follow some of the advices I have given above.

The modified code returns an index to the closest point instead of the coord pair itself. Then it uses that index to look up zone in another String array. NOTE: There is no error checking made that the return index is valid.

```
public class ClosestPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int X = 0;
        final int Y = 1;

        // input coordinates to search against
        double[] coordinate = {37.423423, -122.083953};

        // input points to search against
        double[][] points = {{37.00, -121.50},  // 0  A1
                {37.00, -122.00},  // 1  A2
                {37.00, -122.50},  // 2  A3
                {37.50, -121.50},  // 3  B1
                {37.50, -122.00},  // 4  B2
                {37.50, -122.50},  // 5  B3
                {38.00, -121.50},  // 6  C1
                {38.00, -122.00},  // 7  C2
                {38.00, -122.50}   // 8  C3
        };

        String[] zonenames = {
                        "A1",
                        "A2",
                        "A3",
                        "B1",
                        "B2",
                        "B3",
                        "C1",
                        "C2",
                        "C3",
        };

        //double[] closest = nearestPoint(coordinate, points);
        int index = nearestPoint(coordinate, points);
        double[] closest =  points[index];
        String zone = zonenames[index];

        System.out.println("("+closest[X]+", "+closest[Y]+")");
        System.out.println("Zone: " + zone);
        double d = distance(coordinate[X], coordinate[Y], closest[X], closest[Y]);
        System.out.println("Distance: "+ d);
    }

    public static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        double x = Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2);
        return Math.sqrt( x + y );
    }

    //public static double[] nearestPoint(double[] coordinate, double[][] points) {
    public static int nearestPoint(double[] coordinate, double[][] points) {
        final int X = 0;
        final int Y = 1;
        int indexFound = 0;
        double[] closestPoint = points[0];
        double closestDist = distance(coordinate[X], coordinate[Y],
                closestPoint[X], closestPoint[Y]);

        // Traverse the array
        for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            double dist = distance(coordinate[X], coordinate[Y],
                    points[i][X], points[i][Y]);
            if (dist < closestDist && dist != 0.0) {
                closestDist = dist;
                closestPoint = points[i];
                indexFound = i;
            }
        }

        //return closestPoint;
        return indexFound;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Eirik, I came up with something similar but this is organised much better than what I had come up with and the output is exactly what I needed thank you